# JavaFx ImageView

Tags: javafx

How to clear the contents of the ImageView object so that I can use the PixelWriter object to redraw an image?

Thanks

e.g.

```
ImageView tmpView = new ImageView();
WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage(width, height);
PixelWriter pixelWriter = writableImage.getPixelWriter();
...
tmpView.setImage(writableImage);
...
//draw the first image
...
//clear the contents of tmpView  
//???

//redraw imgView
pixelWriter.setColor(x, y, color);
```

Comment: Why not just create a new `WritableImage` and set it in the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the argb color model, `0` represents transparent. Since a `new int[n]` creates an `int` array of length `n` with all values initialized to `0`, the following will make all the pixels transparent:

```
pixelWriter.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
    new int[width*height],  0, width);
```

If you want all the pixels to be white (for example), then you can fill the array with the appropriate value:

```
int[] white = new int[width*height];
Arrays.fill(white, 0xffffffff);
pixelWriter.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(),
    white, 0, width);
```

Another option is just to create a new `WritableImage` and set it in the image view.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any further details of the original task I'd use a Canvas here instead of an Image/ImageView. With the drawing capabilities of the Canvas you can easily clear the area without having to create possibly huge arrays which have to be filled with color values.